# Path "/src/app/app.module.ts" already exist

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I try to create a new angular project (ng new project-name), but it gives me an error (Path "/src/app/app.module.ts" already exist.).

versions : 
- node v10.6.0
- @angular/cli@7.0.3
- npm 6.2.0

Comment: You're already in an Angular project folder, probably.

Comment: just delete everything in current folder and then try with the same command you mentioned in your question(ng new projectName)

Comment: @msanford No, I am not in an Angular project folder...

Comment: @AlokDeshwal There is nothing in the current folder.